# Cocoa: how to nest a button inside a Table View cell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Take a look at the top pane of the Xcode window.

There's a table list, with checkboxes in one of the columns. That's the interface I want to do.

So how do you nest a button in an NSTableView cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the data cell of the column to an NSButtonCell. In IB you can simply drag a checkbox cell (*not* a checkbox button!) to the column to assign it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I'm finding the only two things I can drag these cells into are Table View and Matrix -- is that accurate?

Comment: For the most part, yeah. Anything that logically could accept any kind of cell should be able to accept them.

Comment: The IBAction triggered by the button is passing the Table View object not the button -- is that normal? Maybe it's because the whole row in my table is getting selected currently when the button is clicked? I can work around it but would be nice to be able to get the button's on/off state.

Comment: Yes, it's normal. The control is the table view.

What you should be doing is updating your model via the `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` data source method, and doing any side-effects there.

Comment: Well, you might be able to get away with them, if you check the `-clickedRow` and `-clickedColumn` of the table sending the action…though I usually do the stuff in the data source methods.